# How do you create a templates folder when you're working with Flask?

Tags: python, frameworks, web, flask

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

When the instructions under "Rendering Templates" directs you to create a templates folder, where exactly do you make it? In your project directory? And how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had read a bit further down in the link you pasted, you would have found:

> Flask will look for templates in the templates folder. So if your
>   application is a module, this folder is next to that module, if it’s a
>   package it’s actually inside your package:
>
> Case 1: a module:

```
 /application.py
 /templates
     /hello.html
```

> Case 2: a package:

```
 /application
     /__init__.py
     /templates
         /hello.html
```

The most common is case 1 - for which you simply create a directory called `templates` and add your templates there. Nothing special about it.

Comment: Yes I did read it but I wasn't entirely still sure. To clarify, does this mean that templates is in the same directory that application.py is in?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.